# Transfering data from one MongoDB server to another while eliminating users/authentication

Tags: mongodb

I am transferring MongoDB databases from one server to another.  The servers cannot talk to each other, so I must use mongodump/mongorestore.  The 'from' server used authentication for the databases.  The 'to' server is in a secure environment, so I'd like to completely obliterate any security/authentication features from the database.  Is it as simple as just deleting the *users

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just `db.system.users.remove({});` for each database.

It seems a bit harder to drop the `system.users` collection, see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4302 but it shouldn't hurt anything if it's empty.

The authentication part is enabled when you run `mongod` with `-auth`, so don't put that in your startup script or config file (comment out `auth=true`, or put `auth=false` if you're running 2.0+).